# How to break a promise chain during DB insertion if data is already present in DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

I am using mongoose to create a new member entry in DB after checking if member is already present in DB or not. If member already present, I need to return a response otherwise proceed to insert new.
Below is the code:

```
createNewMember = (req, res, next) => {

Member.findOne({email: email}).exec()
    .then((members) => {
         if(members == null || members.length==0) {
              // create newMember object
              return newMember.save()   // 1 --> promise returned
         } else {
             res.status(409).json({message: "Member already present"})    // 2 --> I want to return 
         }
     })
     .then((result) => {
          if(res.statusCode === 409) return res;  // 3 --> I added this hack to resolve the problem
          return res.status(201).json({message: "member created"}); // 4 --> then block for newMember.save()
     })
     .catch(err => {
          // handle error and return error response
     })
```

What I want is to break the promise chain if flow goes to point 2 but the second then block is getting called. Point 3 is the check I added to prevent the second then block from getting executed, but I don't think that it is the best way to handle it.
I believe that it is a common scenario, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Don't use a chained promise. Use a nested promise on `newMember.save()`

Comment: Alternatively, use async/await and avoid thenable hell.

Comment: A few years ago I think it was reasonable to try and help people fix their then/catch code, but today I think all this stuff should just be rewritten with async/await. It would be strange if you didn't have access to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things become easier if you rewrite your logic using `async` and `await`:

```
createNewMember = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const members = await Member.findOne({email}).exec();
        if (members?.length) return res.status(409).json({message: "Member already present"});
        // create newMember object
        // ...
        await newMember.save();
        res.status(201).json({message: "Member created"});
    } catch(err) {
        // handle error and return error response
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this makes the code cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: Glad to hear you like it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no breaking out of a promise chain besides throwing your own Error and jumping down to the catch block. But, you don't want to use Error's like that since the situation is not an Error per se, it's just a certain logical circumstance (the member already exists).  I'd recommend thinking of your `.then()`s as cake layers with separate concerns like so:

```js
Member.findOne({email: email}).exec()

    // DB layer
    .then((members) => {

         // If member does not exist, begin saving and return promise
         if(members == null || members.length==0) {
              // create newMember object
              return newMember.save()   // 1 --> promise returned
         } 

         // If member exists, return undefined
         else {
             return;
         }
     })

     // Response Layer
     .then((newMember) => {
         let statusCode;
         let message;

         // On .save() success, the promise resolves to the new member
         if(newMember) {
           statusCode = 201;
           message = "member created";
         }

         // If we returned undefined in the first then(), we'd land here
         else {
           statusCode = 409;
           message = "Member already present";
         }

         return res.status(statusCode).json({message});
     })
     .catch(err => {
          // handle error and return error response
     })
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation on how to handle such situation in promise.